# GTM - no permission

Tags: google-tag-manager

I configured Google Tag Manager Server Side on my custom server.
GTM preview and debug work fine, but when I try to load gtm.js from my html page I get this 403 error:

> Your client does not have permission to get URL
> `/gtm.js?fps=s&id=GTM-XXXXX` from this server.

How do I solve it?